# What are signs to hire a CIO?

Tags: culture

If for example the number of complex Java issues is over growing exponentially on the backlog this could be a sign to hire a Senior Java Engineer, but what are signs for hiring a CIO?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to [workplace.se] or some other management related site, but that's loosely related to devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign to hire a CIO is that your CEO is not able to handle the relevant tasks on his own, plain and simple. The reasons for that may be manifold - maybe he has too much on his plate, as the company grows, or he does not have a sufficiently technical background, etc.

Comment: The CEO could also sign a COO first. Why should he or she sign a CIO instead?

Comment: A COO should have little or less influence of the IT strategies the company should adopt. His responsibility is to coordonate operating activities such as maintenance and support. The CIO differencitae himself by making the decision about IT related activities without respect to maintenance and support. They are exclusive in that sense. Hence, if the CEO spend a big portion of his time on IT decisions, he better rely on a CIO to help him out.